# Coding Probability in Swift

Tags: swift, probability

I want to write a program that creates say 100 squares, with the following rules:

- up to - but no more than 10% of them will be blue
- up to - but no more than 15% of them will be red
- up to - but no more than 25% of them will be yellow
- and the rest of them will be orange

So basically every time I run the App I'll get totally different results. For example, the first time I might get:

- 9 blues
- 13 reds
- 18 yellows
- and 60 oranges

The next time I might get:

- 6 blues
- 14 reds
- 23 yellows
- and 57 oranges

And so on.

I tried doing this using random numbers but every single time I get the absolute max # from each color category - I basically never had any classes in Probability (or Statistics) so I really have no idea what I'm doing here - thought maybe someone could point me in the right direction or knows how to do Probability in Swift code...?

Comment: Insert your code into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will return an array of 100 randomized `UIColors` matching your probability requirement.  This code includes a probability of zero for each of the three main colors.  If you want to include a probability of at least one of each color then change the range to `1...n`

```
func generateRandomColors() -> [UIColor] {

    var randomColors = [UIColor]()

    randomColors += Array(repeating: .blue, count: .random(in: 0...10))
    randomColors += Array(repeating: .red, count: .random(in: 0...15))
    randomColors += Array(repeating: .yellow, count: .random(in: 0...25))
    randomColors += Array(repeating: .orange, count: 100 - randomColors.count)

    return randomColors.shuffled()
}
```

Comment: `.init(repeating: .blue, count: .random(in: 0...10))` Swift is a type inferred language

Comment: The Swift Language Guide does not show the use of .init(repeating:), but Array(repeating:).  I appreciate that it can be done both ways.

Comment: Actually my main point was the `Int`. count expects an `Int` the same way the element expects a `UIColor` which you have omitted.